# Package install includes Groovy and Kotlin but no Java

Tags: android, react-native

I will install Applovin in my React native project. The installation documentation includes Groovy and Kotlin. Should I consider the locations described for Groovy when installing in my own project?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can add Android dependencies in your brake gradle files.